# How to enable access logging in nuxeo?

Tags: tomcat7, nuxeo

I am unable to enable access logging in nuxeo. I tried to enable access logs from the server.xml file. But, the entries flush away on every application restart.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're trying to do is activate the `org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve` in `conf/server.xml` to get an `access_log.txt` or similar file, then what Julien says is true: because `conf/server.xml` is generated from a template (`templates/common-base/conf/server.xml.nxftl`), you must edit the template, or, much better, follow the doc [Configuration Templates](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/0AB9) to understand how to customize Nuxeo without modifying its own files (which may be overwritten after an upgrade).

Comment: Thanks Julien and Florent for your suggestions. I am now able to get the access_logs.txt but there is still an issue. What i required was the logs of users accessing nuxeo but this doesn't seem to solve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

What is your Nuxeo version?

There are audit logs in Nuxeo that you can consult in the "Admin Center / Activity / Events" tab, directly in the database (table "`NXP_LOGS`"), querying the Audit service...
See [NXDOC/Audit](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/UgYuAQ). The service is configurable so to log some specific informations.

There is also a ["Document access tracking Marketplace Package"](https://connect.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/marketplace/package/audit-web-access) enabling the tracking of access hits on a document.

Finally, you can still customize the Tomcat configuration but **not directly editing the server files** which are generated from templates. You must use a custom configuration template: see [ADMINDOC/Configuration Templates](http://doc.nuxeo.com/x/0AB9).
Note you could deactivate the server files generation with "`nuxeo.force.generation=false`" parameter set in `nuxeo.conf` file (for a one shot usage) but this is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, this is what i did finally:

Deactivated the server files generation with "**nuxeo.force.generation=false**" parameter set in **nuxeo.conf** file.

**Modified the Log Format:**

We can extend the "common" and "combined" patterns by appending the response time for each request. To use this, set the

```
common: pattern="common"
common plus response time: pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b %D"
combined: pattern="combined"
combined plus response time: pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; %D"
```

Thanks to you all for helping out! I share my technical views [@Coolcoder](http://coolcoder.in).